# Login with Facebook button issue in magento site

Tags: facebook, cookies, magento, authentication, logout

I have installed the fbconnect module of magento on my website and the 'Login with Facebook' button is there on this page:

https://www.scopial.com/customer/account/login

Whenever a user clicks this button it can be logged into the site using facebook account. But when the user is already logged into the site with facebook and when the user logged out of his facebook account and then comes back to the magento site and logged out from the magento site and then coming back to login page again, the facebook button disappears from the site.

I think this may be the issue of browser cookies as when i am clearing my browser's cookies, the facebook button is appearing there.

Answer (score 0):

That account appears to be suspended in your example.  However, you can find a lot of helpful information now on Facebook's developers website. See specifically https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/